# GCP compute engine network egress attack

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have observed very high egress traffic on gcp dataproc vm which cost ~1000  USD.

> Compute Engine Network Internet Egress from Americas to Americas.

I took follow up with google support and they suggested to improve security.
1. Service account keys
2. Provide password/ certificate auth for open ports on external network (http and https)

So we created new gcp account and decided not to allow any http and https traffic to our dataproc instances. 
So no ports were open to public and created dataproc cluster with all default settings.

But again on these new gcp vm we oberved same egress.

We had gs bucket on same region.

There was not much data on vm or bucket but still there was network egress in TB's.

And we have oberved these senario only in US region, in south asia region till now we have not oberved any egress yet.

I think this could be attack.

Please let me know if some one else has observed same thing.

Please help to avoid such egress

Firewall rules
[image]

http and https firewall rules were not applicable on Dataproc vm

Comment: Are you sure no ports were open to the public? Could you list all your firewall rules including their "inbound IP range" settings and "ports" settings?

Comment: @DennisHuo - I have not explicitly opened any port to public network. I believe default dataproc settings do not have any ports open rather than ssh@22.
I have added firewall rules to question

Comment: Do you have a support package to file a support ticket containing your project id? Or you can send your project id and/or project number to dataproc-feedback@google.com and reference this stackoverflow question. The firewall rules you've shown should be safe. It would be good to verify the exact GCS bucket location settings (`gsutil ls -L -b gs://YOUR_BUCKET`) and the exact locations of the dataproc clusters; keep in mind that for example us-east1 and us-east2 are different regions and would cause egress costs. I'd also check your audit logs to see if the firewall rules were modified recently.

Comment: We've confirmed in a separate email thread that there was indeed a firewall rule that opened "all" protocols/ports to all inbound IP addresses at priority 1000, so the suspected root cause was indeed confirmed. Following up in that thread now to determine why the "allports" firewall rule didn't seem to show up in the firewall list, whether it was a timing of deletion/creation of the rule, using a different project, or a bug in the UI to fail to list all firewall rules.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have been hacked because you opened up YARN REST API port (the same as YARN Web UI) to Internet in firewall rules:
https://medium.com/@neerajsabharwal/hadoop-yarn-hack-9a72cc1328b6

You need to delete cluster and delete firewall rules that granted Internet access to Dataproc VMs, see warning here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces